# Accessing a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My `var_dump` of `$info` looks like this:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(5) "dummy"
    [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "Karaffen" [1]=> string(16) "Ã–l auf Leinwand" [2]=> string(11) "83 x 120 cm" [3]=> string(3) " - " [4]=> string(1) "1" }
    [2]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "SantÃ©" [1]=> string(16) "Ã–l auf Leinwand" [2]=> string(11) "80 x 100 cm" [3]=> string(3) " - " [4]=> string(1) "1" }
    [3]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Landleben I" [1]=> string(16) "Ã–l auf Leinwand" [2]=> string(11) "70 x 100 cm" [3]=> string(3) " - " [4]=> string(1) "1" }
}
```

I expected to get access by this: `echo $info[1][0];` but the echo is always `NULL`.  What's wrong?

Here is the complete code:

```
$info = array();


$info[0]  = "dummy";

$info[1] = array();
$info[1][0] = "Karaffen";
$info[1][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
$info[1][2] = "83 x 120 cm";
$info[1][3] = " - ";
$info[1][4] = "1";

$info[2] = array();
$info[2][0] = "Santé";
$info[2][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
$info[2][2] = "80 x 100 cm";
$info[2][3] = " - ";
$info[2][4] = "1";

$info[3] = array();
$info[3][0] = "Landleben I";
$info[3][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
$info[3][2] = "70 x 100 cm";
$info[3][3] = " - ";
$info[3][4] = "1";


$numFiles = count($info);
echo $numFiles." sind da<br>\r\n";

var_dump($info[1]);


$t = "<br>\r\n";  $i = 0;
echo $t."here: ";
echo $info[1][2];
echo " END";
```

Comment: What's the response you get from `$info[1]`?

Comment: Your `$info[1]` has only 5 keys, so there are no `$info[1][10]`. Wich element do you want to access? I think you want `$info[1][4]`

Comment: @lolka_bolka He said `$info[1][0]`, and not `$info[1][10]`.

Comment: after he edited the post.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure, your array called $info?

Comment: var_dump($info[1]) gives: array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "Karaffen" [1]=> string(16) "Ã–l auf Leinwand" [2]=> string(11) "83 x 120 cm" [3]=> string(3) " - " [4]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: @hamburger show us more code where your using the array and where do you echo it!

Comment: @lolka_bolka, you can see the first version. @hamburger, thats really strange. It was supposed to work... In the after line, if you `var_dump` `$info`, it still gives you `NULL`?

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was my fault. I missread it.

Comment: @hamburger and what's not working? It works all fine for my and i can output `$info[1][0]`

Comment: @hamburger With `echo $t."here: "; echo $info[1][0]; echo " END";` I got this `here: Karaffen END`

Comment: @hamburger What im intressted it now is which echo from your code above gives `NULL` ? Also you never echo `$info[1][0]` in your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. I use answer to format code, this is not in comment:

```
$info = array(
    "dummy",
    array("Karaffen", "Ã–l auf Leinwand", "83 x 120 cm", " - ", "1"),
    array("SantÃ©", "Ã–l auf Leinwand", "80 x 100 cm", " - ", "1"),
    array("Landleben I", "Ã–l auf Leinwand", "70 x 100 cm", " - ", "1")
);
var_dump($info[1][0]);
echo ($info[1][0]);
```

Output:

```
string 'Karaffen' (length=8)
Karaffen
```

Comment: ok it gives:  string(8) "Karaffen" How to get now only "Karaffen" ?

Comment: it works. I'am new in PHP and a little bit insecure. The issue was a typo: echo $Info[1][2]; do not work. thx for your sympathy.

Answer (score 0):

The Code has no error so this should work:

```
$info = array("dummy",
            array("Karaffen", "Ã–l auf Leinwand", "83 x 120 cm", " - ", "1"),
            array("SantÃ©", "Ã–l auf Leinwand", "80 x 100 cm", " - ", "1"),
            array("Landleben I", "Ã–l auf Leinwand", "70 x 100 cm", " - ", "1")
        );


echo $info[1][0];
```

Output:

```
Karaffen
```